# How to draw shapes on image and allow zoom on html page

Tags: javascript, html, image, zooming

Please help,

Is there a solution for getting an image, draw some shapes on the image by x,y points, dispaly it on html page and allow the user to zoom in and out on the image?

Comment: `canvas` and a sense of adventure.

Comment: You can use [Raphael JavaScript Library](http://raphaeljs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo : http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_zoom_to_cursor.html

Read this and try http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/html/9781449308032/images-on-the-canvas/zooming_and_panning_an_image#image_pan_and_zoom_application

I think this article will help you

Comment: Thanks a lot Praveen, 
Solved by your answer.